# Mudline leaking in basement

Tags: basement, leak

I have a new construction home that leaks in the basement near where the frame meets the foundation. The house is on a slope, so the rear has above ground windows.

An attempted solution by the builder was to caulk the inside and foam the outside. The foam wasn't done on the outside between the siding properly, as most of the foam wasn't anywhere near where it needed to be.

The inside regular caulk was used but I think due to the house settling and it not being silicon it's no longer holding up.

Could the bolts holding the frame to cement need to be tightened?

What are the proper steps to take to correct this?  It was really windy and rainy last night so I snapped pictures of the action..  also, the insulation on the adjacent walls I can see moving back and forth,  like air pressure sucking it in, is this normal too?

My furnace draws return air in from the outside but I am not sure what it's using for combustion, if the basement gets a good seal from the outside, do I need to worry about carbon monoxide? Or is that more for older houses.. house is equipped with detectors.

The grade seems okay outside as it's about 6 inches below the window and is flat away from house. But i am not sure.  Warranty is almost up, so I want to make sure this next fix is the last.

[image: leaking at frame and cement]

[image: leaking hire up]

[image: outside]

Comment: Can you show outside pictures.... Does the rain puddle outside that wall above the concrete level? Is it just leaking at the window? You may want to get an independent inspector to come check it out too so you have something "concrete" to force the builders hand.

Comment: Sure, I can get pictures later on tonight when I get off work. It's hard to say, this really only happens when it's blowing rain, I don't believe there is any puddling up against the house because I never do see it when I try to look at the time. And there are areas around the window that is leaking too, and below the window at the frame.  So I am not sure if it's the frame area that water is rushing up under when the rain is blowing, or if it's running down behind the siding and finding it's way in.

Yea maybe I should get someone else to come out too. Good idea.

Comment: If it is not puddling over the concrete level it sounds like they did not install flashing properly. Caulking is not a real solution for that.

Comment: Should there be flashing where the frame meets the cement? I think right now it's the frame at cement, and then sheet of plywood that drapes over a little and then there version of tyvek with siding over it. I do remember though some of that lining that goes between the frame and the cement must have blown out while placing the frame as it was curled in and out in some areas. Although there is leaking in other areas too. And also, the stud the frame is fastened to the nut wasn't fastened tightly.. I will follow up with what their solution is.

Comment: Ideally either the siding should extend down past the cement, there should be flashing under the siding that does the same, or both. The tighter bolts thing is not really a solution. Even if tightened that much, it  just means the outside of the wood gets to rot first... Besides,, you could NEVER get it tight enough unless there was a nut every six inches..

Comment: I was able to dig up an old photo from when they had siding removed while looking at it the first time. I will take some more outside photos when i get home.  The picture i posted is the the right side window when facing backyard from basement.

Comment: That looks like they flashed it right... there anyway.

Comment: This might seem like an odd question, but looking at that outside wall. Which way does the wind usually blow..... Left to Right ?

Comment: I'd be alarmed by the fact that anyone tried to solve this issue by caulking the *inside* of the wall. Talk about missing the boat. If the water is in the wall, there's a problem. Stopping it from entering the room doesn't solve it.

Comment: @Trevor it comes off the field, so right to left.

Comment: @isherwood well in their defense the attempted to caulk the outside with foam, but the guy doing it missed his target entirely.

Comment: Right to left.. ok @eaglei22, then at least the installed the siding the right way round. (common mistake..there is a right way and a wrong way :) )

Comment: I'd check the openings in the siding too though. In the last image there is something , I can't tell what, sticking through the siding to the left of the window. Those are often the source of leaks since they never quite fit right. I always calk around those and check them every few years.

Comment: @Trevor if you click on the image you should be able to zoom in to it. I uploaded to original resolution photo, I took with my galaxy S7 :)..  that might be the electrical outlet.

Comment: Ya I did that, it has a "clear" plastic cover over it so yes I was assuming its electrical, but even zoomed in you can't really tell. Either way. because the backing plate on those is flat, and the siding isn't, they tend to be a source of leakage.

Answer (score 3):

You said, "The warranty is almost up." First, I'd get their contractor's license number (CCB number) and notify your state's Construction Contractors Board. (If they won't give it to you or you can't find it, call your local building code office.) The CCB can help you file a claim against the contractor and attach his bond, if necessary. They've had at least one chance to fix the problem and I'm not sure you want them back to try again and again... (By the way, that feeble attempt to fix the problem by caulking the interior face of the framing, is also warranted. So, technically, you have a warranty period for that work too, but I'd make sure all the paperwork was turned in before the original warranty expires.) Also, you need "the repair" fixed now too, because they have created a moisture problem by trapping moisture in the wall (between the sill plates) which will lead to mold and dryrot.

Now the leak: 1) water on concrete mudsill means water is either splashing UP from surface water on exterior, or running DOWN from the window. I doubt if it's splashing up, because the leak occurs at just the window location. If water was splashing up, you'd see wet spots all along the mudsill. 2) water seems pretty evenly distributed under the window...maybe even a little more in the middle of the sill. Usually, when water gets in at the head or jambs, we find water has run down the jambs and is concentrated at the bottom of the jambs on each side of the window. 3) windows are made with grooves along the sill for window panels to slide in. These grooves have "weep holes" that allow water to escape. If the weeps are plugged (or damaged) the sill could leak. OR, if the contractor screwed or nailed down through the vinyl window sill it could leak around the screw hole. Also, there are "stops" (small notches) cut into the window frame that allow the sliding pane to lock into a partial open position. If that notch is cut wrong, water could leak through the frame. Also, check the window frame joint where the jamb meets the sill. It is suppose to be "welded" closed, but sometimes the window is dropped and it could crack loose. You're looking for a "hairline" crack.

I recommend you do a water test. Turn your water hose on and hold it in one place for about 10-15 minutes. See if it leaks, if not, move to a new spot. Start with bottom and work up. So, start with sill, then center of fixed pane, then center of sliding pane, then jambs, then head. (Just because some siding is removed doesn't mean you can't do the hose test.)

So here's some bad news...if this window leaks, others probably do too.  Just because you don't have water running down the inside of your house under other windows don't mean they aren't leaking. Is there another window with the same wind exposure that you could "pop" the interior sill trim off and check for moisture?

By the way, why did he caulk between all the sill plates? Was there water coming out from between each sill plate, or did he return on a sunny day and didn't see any standing water so he tried to seal everything?

Comment: Great information Lee. I had the same concerns about moisture being trapped between the frame and the foundation when it was caulked from the inside. I was thinking if anything it should have been caulked/foamed from outside and leave inside an escape for moisture to evaporate.   The original intent was to foam the outside and caulk the inside. there were gaps at the sill so bad that I was getting crickets in my basement...   Well, the guy who attempted to foam outside missed the target entirely.

Comment: Should I remove the caulk from inside at the sill? I will see how the next meeting goes for the fix but I will defentially keep in mind everything you have said. The only other windows are the living area windows, and those seem okay. But you said I can take the window out and pop the seal to look underneath?  Also, if things start getting air tight from sealing up the outside, do I have to worry about carbon monoxide? The furnace draws return air from the outside, and exhausts to the roof, hot water tank exhausts out..

Comment: I was going to caulk the perimeter, but I worry about carbon monoxide, as I was watching the insulation foil was being sucked in and out when it was real windy, so I know drafts are definitely coming in. I just worry about sealing the basement off too much with gas hot water tank and furnace.

Comment: The furnace you don't have to worry about since it's a closed loop and, as long as the furnace/flu is not leaking will not present any problems with a 100% sealed house. The water heater on the other hand could prove problematic. It's good to provide a fresh air source to the furnace room / area, probably via a pipe to the attic or garage if you have one. Right now it sounds like your house is so leaky, that's the last of your worries though.

Comment: I was going to suggest the hose thing too... though I would add, run it for like 5m with someone watching inside then leave the hose off for like 15-20m to see if it takes time for the water to dribble out to where you can see it.

Comment: One thing at a time laddy. Adding an air supply is easy. If your insulation is moving that much, I'd be seriously thinking about getting someone else involved, possible even calling my Lawyer. It's starting to sound like the entire exterior of your house needs stripped down and redone. Insulation moving also means moisture is also getting into the walls, and whatever other critters can get in. The life span of your house is seriously compromised.

Comment: @Trevor i was thinking of caulking the outside mudline all along the outside after leaking problem was addressed as i think that's where most of the draft is coming through, and then worried about sealing it off too much. But I guess I will worry about that later as you stated I have bigger fish to fry

Comment: The issue with caulking in general, is that it prevents moisture and insects from passing, but it also stops air from passing. It can actually make things worse if the water is coming from somewhere else. The wood and insulation above the caulk will be perpetually wet, and will rot in a very short period of time. Some ventilation along the mudline is actually a GOOD thing, though it should not present as a draft. Much better to find and fix the source of the leak.

Comment: Hmmm...I like everything Trevor says, except I'm not sure about the "air leaking at the plate is a good thing."  We try to seal the plate to the concrete with a roll of thin (1/2" thick) batt insulation. Elsewhere, everything else should be sealed up pretty good. I'd do the hose test and see if you can find the leak(s). Also, one curious thing is that the water appears on top of the concrete. That's a long ways to go if the actual window frame is leaking. I'm still confused about that. Maybe the window frame is leaking and it's running down the exterior of those stacked sill plates?

Comment: @LeeSam the first time I shot a hose from the bottom of the siding up and got it to leak, so I am pretty sure it's the concrete area the water is getting in somehow. This only happens with blowing heavy rain too. If it's a decent down pour I don't see any water.

Comment: Good...at least you know where it's leaking...even with your contractor's caulking repair. So, if you seal the plate to the top of the concrete wall, the "leak" will probably just move up to the next higher plate. I think you should remove the lower siding and extend the underlayment, etc. down far enough (4" or so) past the top of the concrete wall. I live in a "high wind" area, so water will run uphill around here. We will seal the underlayment to the concrete with "z" flashing and peel-and-stick tape.

Comment: Fasten the flashing to the concrete wall and then seal the underlayment to the flashing. We make the vertical leg of the flashing about 3"" tall. We will seal the underlayment to the flashing with the same 4" wide peel-and-stick tape that goes around windows AND put a layer of the tape under the flashing so the flashing is "squished" into the tape and permanently seals to the concrete wall. (Did you try the hose test further along the wall? I'm surprised it's not leaking the full length of the wall.)

Comment: Yea, it seemed really centralized around the windows for some reason. It does carry out to just one other area a little farther away. I think it's the way the sheet of plywood rests against it as it overhangs a little, but some areas bubble out a little. Hopefully when the builder comes next week they will remove the siding and I can take pictures. I will mention all of the things you are saying as well to them. Btw, what is your opinion on the water heater/furnace with sealing up the basement further? Worst case scenario it could draw in air from the upstairs correct?

Comment: You say, "My furnace draws return air in from the outside but I am not sure what it's using for combustion." There are 2 kinds of air use: 1) Combustion air for the furnace, and 2) Fresh air for the rooms. So, Do you mean, "...COMBUSTION air in from the outside..."? Is there a 3" pvc pipe leading from the exterior to the furnace?  OR, Do you mean "...FRESH air in from the outside..."? Is there a 8" or so duct from the exterior to your ducts?

Comment: Also, your contractor should have given you the operation and maintenance manuals for the furnace, which will show the recommended installation for this unit. (I assume you are using gas with forced air.) By the way, get a second opinion. This is a safety issue. Don't believe me or your contractor.

Comment: Combustion air is allowed from the exterior or interior. If you have a large basement, there would be no problem. If there is a lack of combustion air, there are a couple of ways to check: 1) remove the cover and hold a match with smoke near the combustion unit and see if the smoke blows away or towards the unit. If it blows away, that's called backdraft and is bad. 2) If there is moisture (or rust, but your unit may be too new for rust) on the frame, this means condensation is present and the unit is not burning completely...

Comment: All of the burnt fuel should go up the chimney. Check to see that the metal pipe is completely sealed (no loose joints) and that the flue is sealed to the chimney. Can you see the chimney on the roof? It should extend a minimum of 24" above the roof line and be a minimum of 10' from any vents, openings, etc. (By the way, the chimney should be doubled walled pipe up through your house.)

Comment: Okay thank you. By air coming in I mean fresh air from outside for the return air supply of the furnace into the ducts. I do not see any pvc pipes leading into the furnace for fresh air to the combustion area. And yes there is a stack dead center of the roof, that goes up about 2ft. It is a full size basement.